# How to set up a subdomain, should I set something for my DNS host server?

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, virtualhost

For example, If I already have a domain `test.com` which point to `/www/test` on my server

How about redirect to `/home/another` folder when user link to `anthoer.test.com`

I added the `test` config file under site-avaliable and enable it, but it didn't work.

I accessed by wget, then got `failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.`

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  another.test.com;
        root /home/another;

        location / {
            root /home/another;
            if (-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$  /$1 break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add A-record on DNS provider:

[image]